# How is Academy Size increased?

Tags: endless-space

In Endless Space, the [Academy](http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Academies) is used to manage your hired heroes.  The size of the academy dictates how many heroes can be hired.

Looking around the interface, I don't see how to expand the Academy size or by what means it can be increased.  There maybe a research item or a game option to increase the Academy size, but I haven't found it yet.

How does a player increase the size of their Academy so that player can have more heroes?

Comment: Look in the West Tree

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only ways to increase the Academy cap that I've found so far are the **[Futuristic Game Theory](http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Futuristic_Game_Theory) and [Perfect Forecasting](http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Perfect_Forecasting) [technologies](http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Technology)**.

**Futuristic Game Theory** grants the Alien Resources boon thingie.

> **Alien Resources**
>       +2 Academy Cap on Empire
>       -10 Turn(s) before new Hero Arrival on Empire

The Horatio get an earlier version of the technology:

> The Horatio have a unique technology of the same name that is
>   identical to this one, except that it costs 680 Science and comes
>   earlier in the tech tree.

From Endless Space Wikia: "**Perfect Forecasting** is a unique technology for the Horatio in the Exploration and Expansion technology tree."

> **Alien Integration**
>       +3 Academy Cap on Empire
>       -10 Turn(s) before new Hero Arrival on Empire